# How to save posts position on homepage after random function?

Tags: posts, query-posts

I use the following code to display a random post on a homepage:

```
<?php  global $query_string; query_posts($query_string . "&orderby=rand"); ?>
```

When the page is refresh posts positions are reversed. Is it possible to retain posts positions for a while? I want that posts positions are change once an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you're querying for posts so that you can pass a seed value into MySQLs RAND function.  If your posts are displayed within the same hour, that seed (and your post order) will remain unchanged.

[This post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-posts-every-x-amount-of-hours?replies=2) shows an example.  I've modified it to show how it might be done by the hour:

> Try it with this in your theme functions.php file:

```
function hour_random_posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $seed = floor( time() / 3600 );
    $orderby = str_replace( 'RAND()', "RAND({$seed})", $orderby );
    return $orderby;
}
```

> Now query for random posts like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand'
);

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'hour_random_posts_orderby' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ....
    }
}
else {
    echo "<p>No posts found</p>";
    ....
}
....
wp_reset_postdata();
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'hour_random_posts_orderby' );
?>
```

Comment: You should not be using `query_posts`, ever. Use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query` instead

Comment: @PieterGoosen - Valid point.  Updated my answer to use WP_query.